# PHP: Not Showing The Right Data Using Echo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, echo

I'm trying to echo a data from my database inside a Modal, The problem is the data showing inside the modal is not the information i am looking for. Look the screenshot below. I clicked the 1st link but the data that show is for the second one.

[image]

Comment: We can't possibly help you without seeing the underlying code. Please edit your Question, providing the code related to the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an "index off by one" logic error (possible referencing an array element starting at 1 rather than 0?).

I agree with Deefour though, need to see a code sample to accurately investigate...

Comment: display the results returned
  while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $title = $row["title"];
  $description = $row["description"];
  $url = $row["address"];
  $cat = $row["category"];
  

  echo "<font size=+1><b><br>$count.)&nbsp;<a href= '' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.bannerformmodal'>$title</a></b></font><br>$description<br><b>Location: $url<br>Category: $cat<br></b>" ;
  $count++ ;
  }                                                                    //Modal: <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $title;
   ?></h4>

Comment: Given the data-target='modal', I am assuming you are using bootstrap. What I don't see is the client side code (javascript/jquery) to update the values (it looks like PHP is writing out the h4 tag's inner html and there isn't any javascript to change it when you select another element on the page). My suggestion, use knockout to bind the values to the modal.  http://aboutcode.net/2012/11/15/twitter-bootstrap-modals-and-knockoutjs.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, anyway, can you help me using your above suggestion? Please add me on facebook: koctaviano2006@yahoo.com.ph, i really need this because of my thesis, Thanks in advance! :)